# aiogram How to replace a file that has already been uploaded by the user

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

My problem is as follows:
The user uploads a file, after which the file successfully gets into the folder, then the user uploads a file with the same name, but with a different content. My program offers him options to replace the file with a new one or not. The problem is in the callback handler. message hendler got a method .download
(await message.document.download(destination_file=destination),but callback handler dosn't have the same method.
Please help me!

Thanks in andvance!

Here is the code:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY, state=FSMAdmin.scan_upload)
async def load_scan_to_postgresql(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.content_type != 'document':
        await FSMAdmin.scan_upload.set()
        await message.answer('Загружать файлы можно только в формате .pdf',
                             reply_markup=markup_back)
    else:
        file_extension = '.' + message.document.file_name.split('.')[-1]
        if file_extension != '.pdf':
            await FSMAdmin.scan_upload.set()
            await message.answer("Документ должен быть в формате .pdf", reply_markup=markup_back)
        else:
            doc = message.document.file_name
            destination = rf"certificates\{doc}"
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['doc'] = doc
            if doc in os.listdir(f"certificates"):
                await FSMAdmin.scan_upload.set()
                await message.reply(f"ФАЙЛ С ТАКИМ ИМЕНЕМ УЖЕ ЗАГРУЖЕН В БАЗУ,"
                                    f"ХОТИТЕ ЗАМЕНИТЬ НА НОВЫЙ?", reply_markup=markup_scan)
            else:
                await message.document.download(destination_file=destination)
                await message.reply(f"НОВЫЙ СКАН СЕРТИФИКАТА ЗАГРУЖЕН В БАЗУ", reply_markup=markup_back)
                await state.finish()
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='replace_scan_yes', state=[FSMAdmin.scan_upload])
async def callback_scan_yes(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state=FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        doc = data['doc']
    destination = rf"certificates\{doc}"
    await callback.message.document.download(destination)
    await FSMAdmin.scan_upload.set()
    await callback.message.reply(f"ЗАГРУЗКА ПРОШЛА УСПЕШНО,СКАН СЕРТИФИКАТА В БАЗЕ"
                                 f"ЗАМЕНЕН НА НОВЫЙ", reply_markup=markup_back)
    await state.finish()
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='replace_scan_no', state=[FSMAdmin.scan_upload])
async def callback_scan_no(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state=FSMContext):
    await FSMAdmin.scan_upload.set()
    await callback.message.reply(f"ЗАГРУЗКА ОТМЕНЕНА,СКАН СЕРТИФИКАТА В БАЗЕ ОСТАЛСЯ БЕЗ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ",
                                 reply_markup=markup_back)
    await state.finish()
```

HERE IS TRACEBACK:

File "D:\Python\Work_helpers\Bilight_SQL\bot.py", line 444, in callback_scan_yes
await callback.message.document.download(destination)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update state data with the document, not the *file_name*.

```
doc = message.document
destination = rf"certificates\{doc.file_name}"
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['doc'] = doc
```

then get the *doc* from state data and download the document by using:

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    doc = data['doc']
destination = rf"certificates\{doc.file_name}"
await doc.download(destination)
```